# An easy lemma in number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the following (easy) lemma.
[image]

Unfortunately, I must admit I'm stuck in understanding why in the second-to-last line that congruence is false.
In general that should be true, so I think it depends on the choice of $\gamma$, but how?

Comment: This is extremely hard to read.  The statement "Let $\gamma$ be the largest value of $z$ for which $p^y\,|\,r^{\delta}-1$" is memorably incomprehensible.  What is the reference for this?

Comment: It is a paper by Olga Taussky-Todd on T-groups "A class of groups"

Comment: I don't understand the second congruence either.  If we expand $(1+p^{\gamma}q)^l-1$ we get a lot of terms clearly divisible by $p^{\gamma+1}$.  The only terms which isn't is $lp^{\gamma}q$.  Now we are done if we know that $p\,\not \vert \, l$ but I don't see why we know that.

Comment: @lulu I think $p^y$ is a typo for $p^{\gamma}$  At least, the next sentence makes sense if you adopt that reading.

Comment: That would be false if, and only if, $p$ does not divide $l$, but I see no clue of whether that is the case or not.

Comment: @saulspatz  I think it was a typo for $p^z$.  Too many variables, bound to cause confusion.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that's what I meant.  I hate this way of putting things.   What's wrong with saying, "Let $\gamma$ be the largest integer such that $p^{\gamma}$ etc.?"

Comment: @saulspatz  I entirely agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the second-to-last line proof, the first congruence $(1+p^\gamma q)^\ell \equiv 1\pmod{p^\gamma}$ is trivial. About the second one, instead, you have 
$$
(1+p^\gamma q)^\ell=\sum_{i=0}^\ell \binom{\ell}{i} (p^{\gamma} q)^{i} \equiv 1+\binom{\ell}{1}p^\gamma q \pmod{p^{\gamma+1}}
$$
hence $(1+p^\gamma q)^\ell \equiv 1\pmod{p^{\gamma+1}}$ if and only if $p^{\gamma+1}$ divides $\binom{\ell}{1}p^\gamma q$ if and only if $p$ divides $\ell q$. But $p$ is coprime with $q$, so this holds iff $p$ divides $\ell$. *This has no reason to hold.* However, just remove it and the proof will make sense. Also, in the first line of the proof there is a typo: that $z$ should be a $y$.

However, **the statement is wrong.** Counterexample:

$$
r=p+1,\,\,\, n=p> 2, \,\,\,\delta=1, \,\,\, m=p^x=p^2.
$$

**Correct statement:** Let $r,n,m,\delta$ be integers with $m\ge 2$ and $m \mid r^n-1$; let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p^x \mid m$ and $\delta \mid n$ and $p\nmid n/\delta$. Then $p\mid r^\delta-1$ implies $p^x\mid r^\delta-1$.

**Correct proof:** Denote by $\nu_p$ the $p-$adic valuation, then by lifting the exponent lemma
$$
x\le \nu_p(r^n-1)=\nu_p(r^\delta-1)+\nu_p(n/\delta) =\nu_p(r^\delta-1).
$$
Therefore $p^x \mid r^\delta-1$.

Comment: Why $\gamma$ cannot be $<x$?

Comment: Sorry, how do you see that $\gamma ≥ x$?

Comment: Probably one must assume that $m$ and $l$ are coprime. However, it will be nice to find an actual counterexample.

Comment: How come that $\gamma \geq x$ in this proof? Argue the other way round and you get the other inequality, this way.

Comment: You are all right; there is a corrected version of statement and proof now

Comment: Your corrected statement seems to be the same as the original one, and your corrected proof relies on the unstated assumption that $n/\delta$ is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Right for the second part, I forgot it. However, the difference with the original one is: $m\ge 2$ and $p\ge 3$. (With $p=2$ the argument would be a bit different.)

Answer (score 1):

The Lemma isn't true as stated.

Example:   $$m=36,\; r=5,\; n=6, \;p=3$$

Then we have $$r^n\equiv 1 \pmod m$$ as desired.

We take $x=2$ and remark that  $3^2$ exactly divides $m$.

Let $\delta =2$.  Then we have $$3\,|\,5^2-1\quad \text {but} \quad 3^2\,\nmid \, 5^2-1$$